# Converting Curl into a Zapier

Tags: curl, post, zapier

Trying to convert this into a POST request on Zapier:

```
curl https://api.synthesia.io/v1/videos  \
  -H "Authorization: ${API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d '{ "title": "Hello, World!", "description": "This is my first synthetic video, made with the Synthesia API!", "visibility": "public", "test": true, "input": [{ "script": "This is my first synthetic video, made with the Synthesia API!", "actor": "anna_costume1_cameraA", "background": "off_white", "soundtrack": "inspirational", "actorSettings": { "horizontalAlign": "center", "scale": 0.9 } } ] }
```

This is what I've loaded in my Zap. Getting a 500 Error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7dp4.png

Answer (score 1):

The `POST` action doesn't allow a raw json payload. For that you'll want to use the "Custom Requst" action (https://cdn.zappy.app/fb00eb81f4ad813c381cde60bfe49964.png).

You can then choose the POST method and use the raw json payload for the `Data`. All other fields would be the same as you had.

https://cdn.zappy.app/b194bc30cf6dea1464a572c592890436.png